# PDO => 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, subquery

I'm trying to run a subquery in my PDO, but the PDO won't have it. Any suggestions?

Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

```
$userId = 1;
$promotionId = 1;

$sql = "
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ( 
            SELECT 
                COUNT(*) 
            FROM 
                promotion_user as spu 
            WHERE 
                spu.promotion_id = p.id AND 
                spu.user_id = :user_id 
        ) as num_uses 
    FROM 
        promotion as p 
    WHERE 
        p.id = :promotionId
";

//$db is the PDO connection
$getPromotions = $db->prepare($sql);
$getPromotions->bindValue(':user_id', $userId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$getPromotions->bindValue(':promotion_id', $promotionId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$getPromotions->execute();
$promotions = $getPromotions->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: This query works when I run it in PhpMyAdmin, but PDO won't run it.

Comment: I take it you're not checking for errors. Who does nowadays? Computers are so perfect, aren't they?

Comment: Just new to PDO. It was a dumb mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your query you wrote:

```
:promotionId
```

When you are binding parameters you wrote:

```
$getPromotions->bindValue(':promotion_id', $promotionId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

You need to write both the same way, promotionId != promotion_id.

So you should change this line:

```
p.id = :promotionId
```

To this:

```
p.id = :promotion_id
```